# If $\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\sin{x}}{1+x}dx=b$, find $\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\cos{x}}{1+x}dx$

Tags: integration

if we Assmue that $\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\sin{x}}{1+x}dx=b$,Find the value 
$$\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\cos{x}}{1+x}dx$$  use the $b$ function expression

I try: let $$b=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\sin{x}}{x+1}dx=\cos{1}\int_{1}^{2}\dfrac{\sin{x}}{x}dx-\sin{1}\int_{1}^{2}\dfrac{\cos{t}}{t}dt$$
and simaler we have
$$a=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\cos{x}}{x+1}dx=\sin{1}\int_{1}^{2}\dfrac{\sin{t}}{t}dt+\cos{1}\int_{1}^{2}\dfrac{\cos{t}}{t}dt$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\int_0^1\frac{\sin x}{1+x}dx=b$$
$$I=\int_0^1\frac{\cos x}{1+x}dx$$

---

$$I(t)=\int_0^1\frac{\cos(tx)}{1+x}dx$$
$$I'(t)=\int_0^1\frac{-\sin(tx)x}{1+x}dx=-\int_0^1\sin(tx)dx+\int_0^1\frac{\sin(tx)}{1+x}dx$$
$$J(t)=\int_0^1\frac{\sin(tx)}{1+x}dx$$
$$J'(t)=\int_0^1\frac{\cos(tx)x}{1+x}dx=\int_0^1\cos(tx)dx-\int_0^1\frac{\cos(tx)}{1+x}dx$$

---

$$I'(t)=-\left[\frac{\cos(tx)}{t}\right]_0^1+J(t)\Rightarrow I'(t)=\frac{1-\cos(t)}{t}+J(t)$$
$$J'(t)=\left[\frac{\sin(tx)}{t}\right]_0^1-I(t)\Rightarrow J'(t)=\frac{\sin(t)}{t}-I(t)$$

and we know that:
$$I(0)=\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x}dx,J(0)=0,J(1)=b$$

---

If we differentiate we get:
$$I''(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{1-\cos(t)}{t}\right]+\frac{\sin(t)}{t}-I(t)$$
now rearrange to get:
$$I''+I=\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{1-\cos(t)}{t}\right]+\frac{\sin(t)}{t}$$

Answer (score -1):

Consider $f(x)=\frac{e^{ix}}{x+1}$.  Using this, we can integrate $f(x)$ and take the real part to equal $\frac{\cos{x}}{x+1}$ and the imaginary 
part to equal $\frac{\sin{x}}{x+1}$.

Now, integrate $f(x)$:
$$I=\int_0^1 \frac{e^{ix}}{x+1} \; dx$$ $$I=\int_1^2 \frac{e^{iu-i}}{u} \; dx$$ $$I=e^{-i} \int_i^{2i} \frac{e^t}{t} \; dt$$  $$I=e^{-i}\left(\text{Ei}\left(2i\right)-\text{Ei}\left(i\right)\right)$$

$$I\approx0.601044+0.284227i$$

Now equating $I$ to the original integral:
$$b= \int_0^1 \frac{\sin{x}}{x+1} \; dx =\operatorname{Im}\left(I\right) 
 \approx 0.284227$$
Similarly:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\cos{x}}{x+1} \; dx = \operatorname{Re}\left(I\right) \approx 0.601044\approx \boxed{2.11466\cdot b}$$